# iPhone 5 uiwebvew issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ios, uiwebview

I have created an app which only loads certain parts of a webpage from our website, our app sends a wordpress url to a php file which then uses a php proxy to load the webpage contents into the uiwebview. However the uiwebview does not load the contents when app is running on an iPhone 5, but practically works on everything else, iPad 2 (iOS 6), iphone 3g (iOS 4.1), the iOS simulator and the ipod touch. Does anyone know why this is the case?

If you need more information or if something is unclear, please let me know.

Thank you for you time and help.

Code:

-App code to load uiwebview

```
    NSString *jobURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.redstarjobs.com/?job=%@",[jobDetails objectForKey:@"PostName"]];    
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bigbluemagic.com/redstarjobs/testing_1/script.php?url=%@",[jobURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
```

-Loading webpage contents php file

http://pastebin.com/pVsgSF4Q

-Proxy php file

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(urldecode($_GET['url']));?>
```

**EDIT**

NSLog of jobURL and urlString, the app is a job listings app, so the url depends on the job.

```
jobURL:http://www.redstarjobs.com/?job=sap-payroll-administrator
urlString:http://bigbluemagic.com/redstarjobs/testing_1/script.php?url=http://www.redstarjobs.com/?job=sap-payroll-administrator

jobURL:http://www.redstarjobs.com/?job=sap-manufacturing-lead-tiffinsolutions
urlString:http://bigbluemagic.com/redstarjobs/testing_1/script.php?url=http://www.redstarjobs.com/?job=sap-manufacturing-lead-tiffinsolutions
```

Comment: NSLog jobURL, urlString and edit your question with the results

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the whole URL all at once, rather than just the end bit.

```
NSString *jobURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.redstarjobs.com/?job=%@",[jobDetails objectForKey:@"PostName"]];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bigbluemagic.com/redstarjobs/testing_1/script.php?url=%@",jobURL];
NSURL *stringUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:stringUrl]];
```

If that doesn't work, call the UIWebView `didFailLoadWithError` method and see what it returns as an error.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it turns out the tester had the wrong version of our app.